# login with username and password by using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, popupwindow

software:python 2.7 + selenium
browser:chrome 57

Hi,

I need to download some report files from a website. There is an os level pop-up window in which i have to input my username and password.

[image]

I have tried a solution which is to input my user name and my password with URL link.
eg: https://username:password@XXX.com

but it does not work because my username includes "\" which would be translated to "/" in URL.

and i also tried to download a software named autoit, but i can not install it in my pc since security issue.

any solutions that i could try for my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Use Robo Class functions

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to authenticate in your case is to use username and password in URL.
You still **can authenticate with your username with "\"** symbol, but you need to **encode it first in URL format**. For example, before forming final URL with credentials you can encode your username with `urllib`. This code should work in Python 2.7:

```
import urllib

username = "user\\name"
password = "password"
username_encoded = urllib.quote_plus(username)
URL = "http://%s:%s@XXX.com" % (username_encoded, password)
print(URL)
```

In the output you should see:

> http://user%5Cname:password@XXX.com

And this URL will work fine with basic authentication (your case)

Comment: hi, sunigos. i have tried this way on my end. it does work on my end. I think chrome would a reason for this. does it work on your end while you are using chrome?

Comment: I had a password with "@" symbol and used such encoding trick with chrome. And it worked for me

Comment: Thanks sunigos, i have chosen a different way to resolve my issue.Thank you so much for your help.